# Batch: Copy files from txt file to folder, and place diffrences in new file

Tags: batch-file

On my work I use the batch script bellow to copy a list of GIF files from one 
folder to another, but I need some help with a small thing.

When my script runs and comes to a line in the text file which it can't find a corresponding file to in the folder it skips the line and don't inform me about it. So the thing i need help with is making a thing in the script that makes a new text file with the lines that it skiped over.

Here is my bat script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (gif.txt) do (xcopy "%%a" "%%~pa\GIF")
```

I hope you understand my problem and can help me with a simple solution.

Best Regards
Dion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (gif.txt) do if exist "%%a" (
 xcopy "%%a" "%%~pa\GIF"
) else (
 echo %%a>>skipped.txt
)
```

should do the job (untested)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  
I have tested the script now, and it does make a new file called skipped.txt but the only info in the file is %a
I need it to write the skipped lines from the gif.txt file into the skipped.txt file

Comment: Please make sure that the script is *exactly* as posted. The positioning if the parentheses is critical. If you prefer, the entire script-as-posted may be on a single line, but don't attempt to remove any spaces - these too are critical. Make sure that you are using a proper editor like EDITPLUS or NOTEPAD++. If you are using `notepad` make sure the file is being saved as ANSI. A word-processor may attempt to format the file - it must read exactly as shown.

Comment: It works now after i changed it to ANSI :) thank you very much